# Error Browsing Analysis Services through SMS

Tags: ssas

I get exception: 0x800414154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) while attempting to browse any deployed cubes through SQL Management Studio. I read it had something to do with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 but wasn't sure how to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this problem out about 2 minutes after I posted this question. Microsoft suggests it could be because you had a previous version of SQL Server installed on the same machine and that you should re-register but in my case it was because I was missing the Microsoft Office Web Components (OWC) which can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7287252C-402E-4F72-97A5-E0FD290D4B76&displaylang=en